# How do I override inline style with class declaration using css?

Tags: css, inline

I know that you can use [style] to override style elements within a div or other element, but who do you override inline style calls that declare a style class within them? I cannot change the original code, since it is being pulled in by a 3rd party system. So I'm trying to change the color from black to white via CSS.

Here is the code:

```
<form class="form" id="my-form">
    <style type="text/css">
        form.form p label { color: #000; }
    </style>

    <p class="form-field">
    <label class="field-label">Email</label>
    
    ...
```

I have tried

```
form.form p label{
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

and

```
form.form p label[style]{
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

plus adding a class above, but those have not worked. Suggestions?

Comment: Shoot, that didn't work.

I also realized that I had the code wrong and updated it. I'm trying to change text from black to white.

Comment: Why do you add ```[style]```, simply adding like you did with ```!important``` declaration should work: ```form.form p label { color: #fff!important; }```

Comment: I agree that it should, but I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Is the form an ```iframe``` by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

`!important` should overwrite it.

```html
<style>
  form.form p label { color: red!important; }
</style>


<form class="form" id="my-form">
    <style type="text/css">
        form.form p label { color: #000; }
    </style>

    <p class="form-field">
    <label class="field-label">Email</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Clarification: I cannot change the code that is being output by a third party system, but I do need to come up with the correct CSS to change #000 to #fff.

Comment: Try adding an additional parent selector like ```body``` for example, but just inspecting with the devtools should show you why it isn't overwriting it.